# When doing a scheduled differential backup every 30 minutes, should the filename always change?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-backups

I have a client that has a puzzling thing running on the MS SQL 2008 server.  They have a backup job running every 30 minutes doing a differential backup.

The filename of the backup is the same, so am I right in thinking that the SQL Server 2008 will continuously overwrite this file?  Should the filename be change dynamically on each backup run?   My understanding is that the differential backup is the changes that occurred since the last full backup.  So overwriting the backup each time doesn't make sense to me.

Another puzzling thing is at end of day they have a FULL backup scheduled, and a differential backup at the same time.  My thinking would be that this is also incorrect.

The full backup can occur at end of day, and then differential backups could occur after that, but for them to happen at the same time doesn't make sense.    What would the best practice be for 1 daily backup and then differentials throughout the day?

Comment: To clarify, does a DIFFERENTIAL back-up all the changes since the last FULL backup or since the last DIFFERENTIAL?

Comment: Its probably one file but it will have multiple backups init, you can check by doing a restore headeronly , Also a differentials backup , backups all the changes since the last base backup, a base backup could be a full backup or a differential backup, which means the first diff backup after the full backup will only backup the changes since the last full backup but every subsequent diff backups will only backup the changes since the last diff backup.

Comment: OK so I was right in thinking that your diff backups shouldn't have the same filename each time, as it would overwrite the last one? Or would it add to the previous diff backup?

Comment: it is up to your own preference

Comment: @MichaelFever, `BACKUP` will append by default.  Specify `INIT` to overwrite.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx.